# How do i can use concatLastestFrom?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I am try use effects with my store, but 2 days i have this error:
[image]
Idk why it happened, can u help me please?

[stackblitz simulation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-irgwed?file=src%2Fmeetings%2F%2Bstate%2Factions.ts,src%2Fmeetings%2Fmeetings.component.html,src%2Fmeetings%2F%2Bstate%2Fselectors.ts,src%2Fmeetings%2Fmeetings.module.ts,src%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fmeetings%2F%2Bstate%2Freducers.ts,src%2Fmeetings%2Fmeetings.component.ts,src%2Fmeetings%2F%2Bstate%2Fmodels.ts,src%2Fmeeting%2Fmeeting.component.ts,src%2Fmeetings%2F%2Bstate%2Feffects.ts)

Action:

```
export const LoadMeetings = createAction('[ Meetings/Api ] Load Meetings');
```

Effect:

```
    readonly loadMeetings$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(fromMeetingsActions.LoadMeetings),
            concatLatestFrom(action => this.store.select(fromMeetings.selectMeetingsState)),
        )
    );
```

Selector:

```
export const selectMeetingsState =
    createFeatureSelector<MeetingsStateModel>(meetingsFeatureKey);
//This doesn't work too
const selector = <T>(mapping: (state: MeetingsStateModel) => T) => createSelector(selectMeetingsState, mapping);
export const selectSelectedMeetingId = selector((state) => state.selectedMeetingId);
```

I try find answer in google, docs, youtube, q&a and any services, but zero feed back..
I try change operator map, concatMap, switchMap, pipe and another..
I try change selectors, but zero result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effects usually map to an action ie:

```
readonly loadMeetings$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromMeetingsActions.LoadMeetings),
    concatLatestFrom(action => this.store.select(fromMeetings.selectMeetingsState)),
    map(() => fromMeetings.loadMeetingsSucceeded)
    ), 
);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pq8vlw?file=src%2Fmeetings%2F%2Bstate%2Feffects.ts

If they don't return an action you need to add `{ dispatch: false }`:

```
readonly loadMeetings$ = createEffect(() =>
   this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(fromMeetingsActions.LoadMeetings),
     concatLatestFrom((action) =>
        this.store.select(fromMeetings.selectMeetingsState)
     )
   ),
   { dispatch: false }
);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2yifk?file=src%2Fmeetings%2F%2Bstate%2Feffects.ts

Comment: is it in the documentation? 
If they don't return an action you need to add { dispatch: false }:

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#non-dispatching-effects